# How to use Stetho with Volley?

Tags: android, facebook, okhttp, stetho

Created a volley singleton class for my requests.This is my singleton class

```
public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue reQueue;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        reQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context,new OkHttpStack(new OkHttpClient()));
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return reQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
        request.setTag("app");
        request.setShouldCache(false);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

And m using OKHTTP stack with my Volley implementation.This is my `OKHttp.class`

```
public class OkHttpStack implements HttpStack {

    private final OkHttpClient mClient;

    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
        this.mClient = client;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

        OkHttpClient client = mClient.clone();
        int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();
        client.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder okHttpRequestBuilder = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder();
        okHttpRequestBuilder.url(request.getUrl());

        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        for (final String name : headers.keySet()) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, headers.get(name));
        }
        for (final String name : additionalHeaders.keySet()) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, additionalHeaders.get(name));
        }

        setConnectionParametersForRequest(okHttpRequestBuilder, request);

        com.squareup.okhttp.Request okHttpRequest = okHttpRequestBuilder.build();
        Call okHttpCall = client.newCall(okHttpRequest);
        Response okHttpResponse = okHttpCall.execute();

        StatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(parseProtocol(okHttpResponse.protocol()), okHttpResponse.code(), okHttpResponse.message());
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
        response.setEntity(entityFromOkHttpResponse(okHttpResponse));

        Headers responseHeaders = okHttpResponse.headers();
        for (int i = 0, len = responseHeaders.size(); i < len; i++) {
            final String name = responseHeaders.name(i), value = responseHeaders.value(i);
            if (name != null) {
                response.addHeader(new BasicHeader(name, value));
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static HttpEntity entityFromOkHttpResponse(Response r) throws IOException {
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        ResponseBody body = r.body();

        entity.setContent(body.byteStream());
        entity.setContentLength(body.contentLength());
        entity.setContentEncoding(r.header("Content-Encoding"));

        if (body.contentType() != null) {
            entity.setContentType(body.contentType().type());
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void setConnectionParametersForRequest(com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder builder, Request<?> request)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        switch (request.getMethod()) {
            case Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST:
                // Ensure backwards compatibility.  Volley assumes a request with a null body is a GET.
                byte[] postBody = request.getPostBody();
                if (postBody != null) {
                    builder.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(request.getPostBodyContentType()), postBody));
                }
                break;
            case Request.Method.GET:
                builder.get();
                break;
            case Request.Method.DELETE:
                builder.delete();
                break;
            case Request.Method.POST:
                builder.post(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            case Request.Method.PUT:
                builder.put(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            case Request.Method.HEAD:
                builder.head();
                break;
            case Request.Method.OPTIONS:
                builder.method("OPTIONS", null);
                break;
            case Request.Method.TRACE:
                builder.method("TRACE", null);
                break;
            case Request.Method.PATCH:
                builder.patch(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.");
        }
    }

    private static ProtocolVersion parseProtocol(final Protocol p) {
        switch (p) {
            case HTTP_1_0:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 0);
            case HTTP_1_1:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1);
            case SPDY_3:
                return new ProtocolVersion("SPDY", 3, 1);
            case HTTP_2:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 2, 0);
        }

        throw new IllegalAccessError("Unkwown protocol");
    }

    private static RequestBody createRequestBody(Request r) throws AuthFailureError {
        final byte[] body = r.getBody();
        if (body == null) return null;

        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(r.getBodyContentType()), body);
    }
}
```

I also intilized my Stetho in my application.class

```
Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(
                                Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(
                                Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
                        .build());
```

The issue is when i debug i can't get the network calls made by my application in my browser.Not sure where i am going wrong!Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this file in project [Updated OkHttpStack](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750)

and

Try this:

```
Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new OkHttpStack(client));
```

with following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:(insert latest version)'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:(insert latest version)'
```

Comment: Hello, I'm curious how you handle SSL with OkHTTPStack? I'm currrently using HurlStack with SSL in Volley and would like to switch to OkHTTP so I can use Stetho for network tracing.

Answer (score 1):

the answer of @Sabeeh is correct, only update your libraries in your gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Now in your Application class of your project add this

```
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new OkHttpStack(okHttpClient));
```

Import your libraries and yet we will see an error with ***OkHttpStack(okHttpClient)*** so you only need to copy this code provided by @bryanstern [Class OkHttpStack](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750) so create the file import and enjoy it

Comment: Hello, I'm curious how you handle SSL with OkHTTPStack? I'm currrently using HurlStack with SSL in Volley and would like to switch to OkHTTP so I can use Stetho for network tracing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Stetho for volley without using OkHttp stack.

Please refer this link. [Stetho for Volley](https://github.com/darshan-kapasi/StethoForVolley)